# My Server Got so many CLOSE_WAIT Connections after upgrading the MySQL connector

Tags: java, mysql, tcp, mysql-connector

I am getting so many TCP calls in CLOSE_WAIT state after I have upgraded the MySQL java connector from 5.1.35 to 8.0.20. Those connections remain in CLOSE_WAIT state forever. Can somebody please help me in giving the direction to which I should start debugging?

**MySQL Properties are:**

- interactive_timeout: 28800
- connect_timeout: 60
- wait_timeout: 28800

**The server is resin-4.0.51**

Following is the Stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    - locked <0x000000074bdb0f70> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    - locked <0x000000074bdb1078> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readMessage(SimplePacketReader.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readMessage(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readMessage(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:57)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readMessage(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readMessage(MultiPacketReader.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readMessage(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:533)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:702)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:641)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:940)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:930)
    - locked <0x000000074beac478> (a com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    - locked <0x000000074beac478> (a com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)
    at com.caucho.sql.spy.SpyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SpyPreparedStatement.java:70)
    at com.caucho.sql.UserPreparedStatement.executeQuery(UserPreparedStatement.java:108)
```

Comment: Please provide more info on your environment: Is there an application server involved? Do you use connection pooling? Which operating system?

Comment: Thanks, @Cascader. Yes, the application server is resin. Also, I am updating the post with Stacktrace.

Comment: You should look in the direction of whether you are closing all your `java.sql.Connection` objects: in either `finally` blocks or via try-with-resources statements.

Comment: Thanks, @MarquisofLorne. I checked that. I have found that when I am using the MySQL library mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar. it is working fine. But when I upgrade it to mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar, it is causing the issue with the thread stuck.